# Analyzing the Probability of Passenger Exit Preference in Emergency Evacuations

Tags: simulation, netlogo, cellular-automata

I'm working on an evacuation project where I'm assessing the likelihood of a passenger selecting one exit over another based on the proximity of people in the exit area. However, I'm encountering an issue where the sum of the two probabilities doesn't equal 1. Additionally, I'm unsure about the values to assign when there are no individuals near the exits. How to resolve this problem?

This is the environment: https://imgur.com/ZafKcNc

```
   
to go

  ;; Calcolo PP delle uscite nel vicinato di ogni passeggero
  let sorted-turtles sort passengers
  foreach sorted-turtles [ x -> ask x [

    let cell_exit1 min-one-of exit1 [distance myself] ;;mi ritorna la cella dell'uscita 1 che è più vicina a me, sarà il mio riferimento dell'uscita 1 ; è anche Ri
    let cell_exit2 min-one-of exit2 [distance myself] ;;mi ritorna la cella dell'uscita 2 che è più vicina a me, sarà il mio riferimento dell'uscita 2 ; è anche Ri

    let dist1 [distance myself] of cell_exit1  ;distanza effettiva dall'uscita1
    let dist2 [distance myself] of cell_exit2  ;distanza effettiva dall'uscita2

    let sorted-neighbors sort neighbors
    foreach sorted-neighbors [y -> ask y [

      let dist11 [distance myself] of cell_exit1
      let dist22 [distance myself] of cell_exit2

      ifelse (dist11 < dist1) [
        set pcolor pink
      ]
      [
        if (dist22 < dist2)[
          set pcolor blue
        ]
      ]
    ]]


  ]]

;controllo se sono nell'uscita allora muori
  ask turtles-on exit1 [die]
  ask turtles-on exit2 [die]

  let al-sicuro patches with [pcolor = cyan ]
  ask turtles-on al-sicuro [die]
  move
  tick
end


to move


  let sorted-turtles sort passengers
  foreach sorted-turtles [ x -> ask x [


    let cell_exit1 min-one-of exit1 [distance myself] ;;mi ritorna la cella dell'uscita 1 che è più vicina a me, sarà il mio riferimento dell'uscita 1 ; è anche Ri
    let cell_exit2 min-one-of exit2 [distance myself] ;;mi ritorna la cella dell'uscita 2 che è più vicina a me, sarà il mio riferimento dell'uscita 2 ; è anche Ri
    let dist1 [distance myself] of cell_exit1
    let dist2 [distance myself] of cell_exit2


    ;;PS-DISTANZA in base alla distanza
    let N 2
    let r1 (dist1 ^ Kr)
    let r2 (dist2 ^ Kr)
    let R12 (r1 + r2)

    let PSr1 (1 -  (((N - 1) * r1) / R12) )
    let PSr2 (1 -  (((N - 1) * r2) / R12) )

    ;;PS-OD in base al numero di persone all'uscita
    let d1 count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = magenta] ; HERE
    let d2 count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = sky] ; HERE

    let d1k (d1 ^ Kd)
    let d2k (d2 ^ Kd)
    let D12 (d1k + d2k)

    let PSd1 0.5 ; HERE
    let PSd2 0.5 ; HERE

    ;se ci sono persone dentro l'area1 calcolo PS-OD
    if (d1 > 0) [ set PSd1 (1 -  (((N - 1) * d1k) / D12) )] ; HERE

    ;se ci sono persone dentro l'area2 calcolo PS-OD
    if (d2 > 0) [ set PSd2 (1 -  (((N - 1) * d2k) / D12) )] ; HERE

;
    ;; CALCOLO PS finale in base a SD e OD
    let alpha1 abs (1 -  ((dist1 *  N) / R12)) ^ Kr
    let alpha2 abs (1 -  ((dist2 *  N) / R12)) ^ Kr
    let alpha_tot (alpha1 + alpha2 ) / N

    let beta1 0
    let beta2 0
    let beta_tot 0

    if (D12 > 0)[
      set beta1 abs (1 -  ((d1 *  N) / D12)) ^ Kd
      set beta2 abs (1 -  ((d2 *  N) / D12)) ^ Kd
      set beta_tot (beta1 + beta2 ) / N
    ]


    let PS1 ((alpha_tot * PSr1) + (beta_tot * PSd1)) / (alpha_tot + beta_tot) ; HERE
    let PS2 ((alpha_tot * PSr2) + (beta_tot * PSd2)) / (alpha_tot + beta_tot) ; HERE


    show PS1 ;probabilità finale di scelgiere l'uscita1
    show PS2 ;probabilità finale di scelgiere l'uscita2
    ;show (PS1 + PS2)

    ;;Scelgo verso quale PP spostarmi (PP più vicina all'uscita)
    let PP1 neighbors with [pcolor = pink] ; HERE
    let PP2 neighbors with [pcolor = blue] ; HERE

    let LPP1 min-one-of PP1 [distance cell_exit1] ; HERE 
    let LPP2 min-one-of PP2 [distance cell_exit2] ; HERE


    ifelse (PS1 > PS2)[ ; HERE
        face cell_exit1
        move-to LPP1
    ]
    [

        face cell_exit2
        move-to LPP2

    ]


    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: you really have to do more work for us before asking such a broad, vague question. You have provided no information on what you are doing, how you are calculating these percentages etc.

Comment: This appears to be a modeling question, not a programming one.